# Unbounded representations of groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $G$ be a finitely generated group. Let $\pi:G\rightarrow GL(H)$ be a representation.

A map $c:G\rightarrow H$ is called *cocycle* if $c(gh)=π(g)c(h)+c(g)$ for all $g,h$ in the group $G$. A cocycle  $c$ is *proper* if the map $g\mapsto c(g)$ is proper, i.e., for every constant $K$ the number of elements $g$ in the group such that $||c(g)|| \lt K$ is finite.

**Q1: Does there always exists a representation (bounded or not) of a group on a Hilbert space which admits a proper cocycle?**

the answer to this question is in the comment of Mikael.

**Q2: Does there always exists a representation (by bounded operators) of a group on a Hilbert space which admits a proper cocycle?**

Here we only assume that $||\pi(g)||<\infty$, but $\pi$ is not necessarily uniformly bounded.

Comment: What's a proper cocycle? Sorry to be so ignorant.

Comment: $c$ is proper cocycle if the map $g\mapsto c_g$ is proper, I.e., for every constant K the number of elements $g$ in the group such that $||c_g||$ is finite. 

Comment: $||c_g||<K$ is finite

Comment: If it means what I think it means, then this question as it currently stands is trivial to answer in the negative. Let the Hilbert space be the complex numbers, and take any group whose cardinality is much larger than that of the complex numbers, acting trivially. Then a cocycle is a homomorphism and it the kernel must be huge for cardinality reasons.

Comment: and cocycle is a map $c:G\rightarrow H$ such that $c(gh)=\pi(g)c(h)+c(g)$ for all $g,h$ in the group.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by an unbounded representation? One fixed dense domain for all group elements?

Comment: wccanard, the question is whether there exists *some* representation with *some* proper cocycle.

Comment: I think that Kate meant UNbounded...

Comment: And my guess is that, here, a representation is just a homomorphism $G\rightarrow GL({\cal H})$.

Comment: Domain is the whole space $H$

Comment: Yes, Alain, this is what I meant (both your remarks)

Comment: actually, the my remark about unbounded is bad, I want to include finite groups as well..

Comment: My understanding of Kate's question is this: does any f.g. group admit a proper, affine action on a Hilbert space? Am I correct?

Comment: yes, Alain. Is this equivalent to something known?

Comment: A natural class of counter-examples to try are groups containing expanders. It is quite likely that a proper affine continuous action would imply existence of a uniform embedding in a Hilbert space (possibly a different one), but I do not see how to prove this at the moment.  

Comment: Alain, I am impressed by your guessing the right question from so few information. Kate, perhaps you should edit your question, adding enough details so that people who are not in the field but interested may have a chance to understand it. 

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated and coarsely embeddable into a Hilbert space, then the answer is yes. This follows from Bo\.zejko--Fendler's construction (Arch. Math. (Basel) 57 (1991), 290–298). Otherwise, as Misha, I bet on an expander counterexample. 

Comment: One approach would be to find a mteruc of nonpositive curvature on GL(H)/U(H). 

Comment: What do you mean by unbounded representation? possibly by unbounded operators, or by bounded operators, but with no uniform bound on their norms?

Comment: possibly by unbounded operators

Comment: So you need to assume that $c(h)$ belongs to the domain of definition of $\pi(g)$ for all $g,h$ in your group, right?

Comment: @Kate: sometimes when people edit their question, they leave the old question there and insert new words and write "EDIT" by the new words. The advantage of this would be that very early on I have a comment of the form "let $G$ be a group with huge cardinality" and you have now changed the question so $G$ is finitely-generated, so my comment now looks stupid. But this doesn't bother me -- you're in the hands of the experts now so it seems so I can stop thinking about this question :-) I still don't understand the quantifiers though! I don't know what is given -- the group, the Hilbert space...

Comment: @Yves. If one follows Alain, Kate calls unbounded operator a (not necessarily continuous) linear map on the vector space H. In this case the answer is yes: take an affine isometric action for which $\{g \cdot 0, g \neq 1\}$ are linearly independant vectors, extend this family to an algebraic basis of H, and conjugate your action by some suitably chosen linear invertible map that is diagonal in this basis). In my opinion the interesting question is the one to which Misha and Taka answered.

Comment: @Mikael: I can't guess the question to which Misha and Taka answered, (assuming it is uniquely defined)... also I'm not sure about the precise  meaning of Alain's interpretation since continuity of linear maps is often implicit on affine actions on topological spaces. So in your interpretation of Alain's interpretation, we consider homomorphisms into $GL(H)\ltimes H$, where $GL(H)$ is the full group of invertible linear automorphisms of the abstract vector space $H$ and the subgroup $H$ in the semidirect product is the group of translations, and require it to define a proper action.  

Comment: @ Yves, Mikael: I feel psycho-analyzed, but you are right about how I interpreted Kate's question... (no unbounded operators in my interpretation).

Comment: @ Kate: I think that Taka's excellent comment comes very close to an answer...

Comment: @Yves: yes, this was my interpretation of Alain's interpretation. It seems to be the only way to put together "unbounded operators" and "Domain is the whole space $H$". @Alain: I agree that although we still do not know the question, Taka's comment is a good answer.

Comment: Initially I was thinking exactly about the question that Mikael answered. But now I've got excited about the question which you guessed. I'll added it to the question.

Comment: Narutaka Ozawa answers question Q1 (for abstract representations) in the case of groups coarsely embeddable into Hilbert spaces, but it is not yet fully answered, or do I miss something?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, Taka's comment applies to both questions.

Comment: I think the correct statement is that a fg group properly embeds in  Hilbert space iff it admits a continuous proper affine action on such. Taka noted one direction in this statement. 

Comment: @Misha, Kate: Taka noted one direction. You seem to claim the other direction is true. But I don't see any way, even for a proper cocycle $b$ over a (non-uniformly) bounded representation $\pi$, to deduce a coarse embedding. If you want the orbital map $g\mapsto b(g)$ to be a coarse embedding, you need a uniform bound on $\pi(g)b(s)$ when $s$ ranges over generators and $g$ ranges over $G$. 

Comment: Yves, non-non-non, I don't claim that.

Comment: Yves: I was thinking about Lipschitz cocycles. The Lipschitz uniform Hilbert embedding I have in mind is a much more complicated one: Using a suitable infinite dimensional symmetric space and its logarithmic map. I do not have a detailed proof though since the argument also needs lower curvature bounds. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q1 and Q2 have a positive answer for all countable groups (conversely a discrete uncountable group cannot bear any proper function). Let $\mu$ be a proper function from $G$ to the positive reals, and view it as a discrete measure on $G$. Assume in addition that $\mu$ grows reasonably, and more precisely satisfies an equality of the form $\mu(gh)\le C_g\mu(h)$ with $C_G\>0$ (e.g. fix a proper subadditive length $|\cdot|$ and define $\mu(g)=|g|+1)$.

Then the action of left action of $G$ on itself induces a well-defined left regular representation $\pi$ of $G$ on $\ell^2(G,\mu)$, which is bounded ($\|\pi(g)\|\le C_g^{1/2}$).

Let $e$ be the unit in $G$ and $\delta_g$ the Dirac function at $g\in G$.
Define $b$ as the coboundary $b(g)=\delta_e-g\delta_e=\delta_e-\delta_g$. Then $\|b(g)\|\ge \mu(g)-\|\delta_e\|$, which is proper; thus $b$ is a proper cocycle.